Collision and add force Unity
just new to unity and trying to make a 3d mini video game. I found this game on the internet to be able to launch an object, can you explain the steps to do on unity to make the code work?
{
    public GameObject ball;
    public Transform positionBall;  
int totalMoney = 0;
public TMP_Text =moneyText;

 
    void Start()
    {
        _gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
    }

this in theory is used to get a game object from unity, do I need to connect something?
 void Update()

    {
 MeshRenderer meshLine= line.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
            meshLine.material.color=Random.ColorHSV(0.27f, 0.41f,1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GameObject newBall=Instantiate(ball, positionBall.position, positionBall.rotation);
 
            Rigidbody rb= newBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 


            rb.AddForce(positionBall.transform.forward*20, ForceMode.Impulse);

            Destroy(newBall, 3);              
}

this in theory is used to generate the ball and shoot it on unity do I have to connect something?
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

  {
    Vector3 posizione = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10f, 10f), 1, Random.Range(-10f, 10f));
    Instantiate(money, position, Quaternion.identity);
  }

    }
   private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag=="Player") 
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);   
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
   public void AddMoney()
    {
        TotalMoney++;
        Debug.Log(totalMoney);
moneyText.text=totalMoney.ToString()
}
}




Once you have created the c# script, you can drag-n-drop it onto an empty Game Object (which you create by right clicking in the inspector on the left and hit create>empty).
When you did this you should be able to see the script as a component on the Game Object. There you also find the public variables, as ball, positionBall and moneyText.
First of all the ball variable. It's of type "Game Object". To fill that variable you first want to create a ball in the editor. To do that you right click on the inspector and hit create>3d>sphere. Then on the right you see the components tab. There you click "add component" to add Rigidbody3D. This is crucial to enable physics for your ball.
Once you did that you drag the object from the inspector into your files tab in the bottom. You've created a prefab, a reusable GameObject so to say. Then you can drag that into the variable slot of the script you can see on the right of the object you put the script on.
The positionBall variable is of type Transform. That means position, rotation and scale. You can fill that in by creating another empty GameObject (like described above) which you just drag into the variable slot. This will be the "spawnpoint" of the balls.
The moneyText Variable is of type TMP_Text (text mesh pro, an advanced Text rendering system or something) Just click create>ui>Text mesh pro text and once created drag it into the variable slot.
Now you have assigned all the variables :)
Now you can create other GameObjects and give them the tag Player, which you can create and assign on the top right in the editor.
I hope this helps :)
